Representation based on attribute value in GDB feature class
I use ArcMap. I have one shapefile and it was in symbology categorized based on TWO attribute values:

So shapefile looks like this:

Then I saved as LAYER FILE to have symbology.
But I need to have symbology saved in GDB, so basically I create a GDB with feature class in it. Then through Properties/Representation import my LYR file and got this:

But when I add this feature class from GDB, it looks like this:

but in TOC it´s like this:

what can go wrong, please? what can I do to make it right?
